# How to compare timestamp in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, timestamp

I've this statement:

```
create table times (time_in timestamp, time_out timestamp);
insert into times values(to_timestamp('02-MAY-11 07.57.00.000000 AM'), to_timestamp('02-MAY-11 07.30.00.000000 PM'));
select extract(hour from(time_out-time_in))||':'||extract(minute from(time_out-time_in)) from times;

EXTRACT(HOURFROM(TIME_OUT-TIME_IN))||':'||EXTRACT(MINUTEFROM(TIME_OUT-TIME_IN))   
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
11:33
```

And now, I wanna compare the result above. For example:`IF [result] > [8 hours] THEN ...`

How is to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM times
WHERE time_out - time_in > interval '8' hour
```

Inside a PL/SQL procedure this would look like this:

```
declare
  result interval day to second;
begin

  -- !!! make sure this select returns only one row, or use a cursor !!!
  select time_out - time_in 
     into result
  from times; 

  if (result > interval '8' hour) then
    dbms_output.put_line('greater');
  end if;
end;
/
```